# Select the description of the subjects where all occurrences got more than a 9 in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to get the description of all subjects which students got more than a 9.

I tried using all and such and nothing, any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I am trying to select all the subjects that all the notas are higher than 9 but no idea really

Comment: Just for the future: if you post a question like this, add some kind of code. Here for example you could post your query - the one that comes closest to the result wanted.

Comment: The answer of Kathara was perfect, I added the distinct and worked flawlessly. I am still learning sql but this helped me alot

Comment: Glad I could help ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a join statement (untested):

```
SELECT as.description FROM asignaturas AS as
JOIN notas AS n ON as.codasig = n.codasig
JOIN alumnos AS al ON n.numexp = al.numexp
WHERE n.nota > 9
```

As you didn't specify what value is bigger than 9 I assumed it would be the "nota". Otherwise you'll have to change the where statement according to what you need. Also you might want to add a "DISTINCT" as I don't think you'd want the descriptions multiple times.

This should at least help you get into the right direction.